# Making an ordered Factor

Tags: r, r-markdown

The following code creates a vector called sizes from small to extra-large

```
set.seed(23)
sizes<-sample(c("small","medium","large","extra-large"),50,replace=T)
```

Here I made the attempt to create ordered levels by first creating the factor and then use order to the factor I have created. When displaying the output, I see that they are separated by size. How can I create four order pairs, where small is less than medium, the medium is less than large, and large is less than extra-large?

```
sizes_as_factor = factor(x=c(sizes))
sizes[order(sizes_as_factor)]
```

Comment: Change your line where you are making the factor to make it an ordered factor, and specify the exact level names. You also don't need to do the `x=c(sizes)` thing, just put in `sizes` instead. This line of code should work: `sizes_as_factor  = factor(sizes, ordered=TRUE, levels = c("small", "medium", "large", "extra-large"))`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to make the factor first and then sample from it. It will produce a factor that retains the levels, another potentially beneficial aspect of factors.

```r
sizes <- c("small","medium","large","extra-large")
size_fct <- factor(sizes, levels = sizes, ordered = T) 

set.seed(23)
size_samp <- sample(size_fct, 50, T)
size_samp
#>  [1] small       extra-large extra-large large       extra-large small      
#>  [7] large       large       small       medium      extra-large small      
#> [13] large       small       small       extra-large extra-large large      
#> [19] medium      medium      large       medium      small       medium     
#> [25] extra-large medium      small       medium      large       medium     
#> [31] large       large       medium      large       medium      extra-large
#> [37] small       small       large       extra-large large       large      
#> [43] extra-large small       large       medium      extra-large small      
#> [49] large       medium     
#> Levels: small < medium < large < extra-large
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

By supplying the factor levels manually in the desired order:

```r
sizes_as_factor <- factor(sizes, levels = c("small", "medium", "large", "extra-large"))
```

Comment: OK, so are levels always used inside factors?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what a `factor` is.

Comment: Factors are for categorical data, and the levels are the legal categories. So yes, levels are always used - if you don't supply any the levels will be assigned automatically in alphabetical order.